# AES en-and decrypt PHP MySQL

Tags: php, aes

Well, I definitively rightly chose my nick, as I am baffled over this:

First I encrypt it, and I get an encrypted row in my table. But when I try to decrypt it, I get zero rows as the result set.

Encrypting:

```
INSERT INTO accesobases (company, username,email) VALUES
 ('hola',
AES_ENCRYPT('pedro','capullo'),
AES_ENCRYPT('myemail',' capullo')
);
```

and when I run the decryption query, 0 rows show up.

```
SELECT company,
AES_DECRYPT('username', 'capullo'),
AES_DECRYPT('email', 'capullo')
from acceso
where company = 'hola';
```

Note that I did not encrypt company, but I will definitively need to, but I wanted to see where the error it could be. That is, not even departing from a non encrypted word (company = hola) I get any results. So, it will be even worse when I try to do as:

```
where AES_DECRYPT ('company', 'capullo') = ' " . $company . " '
```

which is how it would look like on my php pages. The above block was being run on the MySQL database itself.

So, the questions are two:

1. What is wrong with not showing any data
2. Whether the version of ..."$company.." will work.

However, if I say:

```
SELECT * from acceso 
WHERE company = 'hola';
```

then, it does show the row with encrypted words

So, it is as if it did not have the time to decrypt the row before showing it and then shows nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are column names, so don't put them in quotes:

```
AES_DECRYPT('username', 'capullo'),
AES_DECRYPT('email', 'capullo')
```

Do this instead:

```
AES_DECRYPT(username, 'capullo') AS username,
AES_DECRYPT(email, 'capullo') AS email
```

Also, since the output of AES_ENCRYPT is binary, ensure your columns are binary.

It also looks like you might have two different tables,  'accesobases' and 'acceso', so ensure you're using the correct table.

Your statement:

```
where AES_DECRYPT (company, 'capullo') = ' " . $company . " '
```

Seems fine, as long as you remove the quotes from the column name here too. It will be slow since it won't be able to use an index. Instead, you should do this:

```
where company = AES_ENCRYPT('$company', 'capullo')
```

Comment: Thank you so much! it worked! and definitively you lightened up my error, they were columns. I ll give you the right answer, just need to wait 5 minutes, the system doesn't let me yet. In the meantime, the second question, will this then be ok when I take it to my php pages: where AES_DECRYPT ('company', 'capullo') = ' " . $company . " '
thank you

Comment: @iaintunderstand, I updated my answer. I didn't see that second question at first.

Comment: In the meantime, I tried on my php pages, it worked. It was all due to that. A whole evening I have spent with that. Thanks a lot. I am into a paranoid security login page where I am going to use prepared statements with AES. By the way, nice tools the MediaPluck of your web.

Comment: Is it possible to credit several correct answers? It is not fair that I am limited to click on only one when everybody has correctly answered. Feel bad about it. All deserve the credit.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT company,
AES_DECRYPT('username', 'capullo'),
AES_DECRYPT('email', 'capullo')
from acceso
where company = 'hola';
```

This won't work because you're telling MySQL to decrypt the constant string "username", not the value of the `username` column. Remove the quotes on `'username'` and `'email'`.

```
where AES_DECRYPT ('company', 'capullo') = ' " . $company . " '
```

Same issue here. However, it'd be more efficient to do this the other way around in order to leverage indices:

```
where company = AES_ENCRYPT(?, 'capullo')
```

---

That being said, using AES_ENCRYPT on the MySQL server side is **NOT SECURE**. The encryption key is passed to the server with each query, and, as such, will appear in the MySQL processlist, as well as potentially in server query, slow, and/or error logs; if you are not using SSL for your MySQL connection, they will be passed over the network in cleartext, as will the decrypted data.

Comment: The more I see people misusing AES_ENCRYPT/DECRYPT, the more I consider their addition to be a mistake. Their existence just encourages people to make inappropriate security decisions.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with making your web site use SSL. What I'm referring to is using SSL to encrypt communications between PHP (presumably?) and MySQL. Most hosts do not support this.

Comment: then, how is this possible? then, nothing is secure. How to do things near 100% safe ?

Comment: Encrypt and decrypt data within your application; don't trust the database with anything crucial. If you're using PHP, you can use the mcrypt extension for the mechanical bits.

Comment: alright, yes, I recently caught sight of the mention about mcrypt but still did not get to it. Tomorrow I ll definitively have a deep dive. Thanks so much, your advices are worth gold.

Comment: So, for example, one of the things that would be interesting to encrypt would be the file that connects to the database ? and the file that contains the "salt" string?